# Import Picture from file to Picture Box

Tags: c#, directory, image

In my project, I have a list box.  When I click an item on the listbox, I want the PNG image from a file (stored in 1Global Varible, GV.dir1) into the Picture Box named picBox... this is what I have...

```
picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(GV.dir + 
                               lstFull.SelectedIndex.ToString() + ".png");
```

`GV.dir` is equal to -> `@"C:\Files"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `\` after `"C:Files"`, and are your png's really named 0,1,2,3...etc.  Using the `.SelectedIndex` property will just return the index number (as a string with the `.ToString`).  I think you may want to use `SelectedItem.ToString` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change this to:

```
var imageFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(GV.dir, lstFull.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".png");
picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
```

Note the use of Path.Combine and SelectedItem.  The first takes care of missing \ characters in your path.  The second will change your text from a number (index) to the text of the item.